# Networking issue with Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, nat

I have a frustrating issue with virtualbox where I am unable to ssh into the virtual machine.

I am using debian on both the host as well as the guest.

```
ip addr on host
    3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
        link/ether 00:26:b6:f5:f3:26 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
        inet 10.0.0.9/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global dynamic wlan0
           valid_lft 48769sec preferred_lft 48769sec
        inet6 fe80::a16d:a4e:4251:d1d9/64 scope link 
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    10: vboxnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
        link/ether 0a:00:27:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
        inet 10.0.0.77/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global vboxnet0
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Guest ip addr:
[image]

i tried to do an nmap and arp-scan but I do not see anything listening and i'm very confused. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check these;
1. VM has a bridged network? then check subnet mask. 
   Two host have different networks and gateway. 
2. VM has a NAT? then you have to configure Port forwarding rule.
   Refer this [link](http://ask.xmodulo.com/access-nat-guest-from-host-virtualbox.html):

Comment: @sirnopes Good to hear that!

Answer (score 3):

Network connectivity to your VM - assuming of course that it has a properly configured service to connect to - depends on what network type you've chosen in the VM settings.

1) NAT   - this does what it says.  Unfortunately, it doesn't create a matching address on your host machine.  The only way to connect is to forward individual ports, just like you would on your home router.  This is done in the manager interface, in the settings for the machine, on the networks tab.  If you have "NAT" selected as the network type and the card is active/enabled, the Port Forwarding button will be active and available.

2) Bridged - this bridges across one of your ethernet devices in the host machine, and connects directly to the network as if it were plugged in to a jack somewhere.  HOWEVER... some work places, schools, etc. do not allow multiple MAC addresses to communicate through a single managed switch port, and if that is the case on whatever LAN you are connecting to it Won't Work.

3) Host Only - this creates a virtual network between your host machine and the guest(s).  There is a dhcp service available, but it won't provide a gateway.  If you want your guests to connect, you'll need to set up NAT/etc on the host machine and provide access that way.

4) Internal only - this connects machines to a virtual internal dumb switch.  No DHCP service, no gateway access, nothing.  Oh, and no matching adapter on your host machine.

What I do for a lot of practice/playground/experimentation is set up one machine with 2 interfaces - one on bridged, and one internal.  I then turn that into a router machine, with a fake domain (fake.tld) DNS service, DHCP, caching DNS service for the world, etc. and then spin up other VMS to actually experiment and do things with on the internal only network.